# Is there a point in saving more civilians in XCOM 2?

Tags: xcom-2

There was a mission where I needed to save 6 and HQ was complaining each time they were lost. Is there really a point in saving more than required by mission (6 in my case)? I mean real bonuses apart from badges, achievements, etc.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if this question also covered "unreal" bonuses like badges and achievements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an achievement<sup>1</sup>:

> Heroes of the Resistance
>
> Beat a Retaliation mission with less than 3 civilian deaths.

Otherwise, as long as you manage to save at least 6, I couldn't identify any difference in the outcome. There are no rewards for Retaliation missions, so there's no difference there.

You are offered a cache of supplies/intel/materials by the Resistance after completing a Retaliation mission, and it's *possible* that differs based on how many civilians you save, but if it does, I couldn't detect it at all. I also looked through the XCOM 2 source released with the mod tools, and there doesn't appear to be any different treatment for Retaliation missions compared to any other type.

<sub>1: According to [skully](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254597/is-there-a-point-in-saving-more-civilians-in-xcom-2/254618?noredirect=1#comment353568_254618), the achievement unlocks from less than 4 civilian deaths, in contradiction to its text. I was also able to confirm this in the XCOM 2 source.</sub>

Comment: Sidenote: It should be "beat a Retaliation mission with less than or equal to 3 civilian deaths" since I got the achievement for rescuing 10/13 civs with 3 dead.

Comment: @skully Huh, interesting - I took that text from the Steam achievement. I'll add a note to the answer, thanks.

Comment: @ChrisHayes when you successfully beat a retaliation mission, the monthly income for that region is permanently increased. I do not know if the increased amount is related to the number of civilians saved though.

Comment: @STTLCU I've taken a look at the script which is responsible for that, but it only depends on your difficulty level. Nothing else factors into the increase. (Also, it turns out the entire continent gets a supply increase, and not just the region the mission was in.)

Answer (score 3):

Saving 6 civilians yields an additional contact gained as an award. Saving eight yields *two* additional contacts.

So far I generally finish clearing out all opposition before saving ten, but I'll try and check sometime if that has any additional effect.

Comment: OMG I'll need to confirm, but this is awesome to know!

Comment: What does "additional contact" mean here? I've saved up to 10 in a mission and never seen such a thing. Do you have to actually move up and rescue them, or is simply having them alive enough?

Comment: @ChrisHayes You need to actively move up and rescue them. "Additional contact" means that once you complete the mission you'll have some people sign on on the Avenger, usually as scientists or engineers.

Comment: Ah, interesting. That's very annoying that you have to actually move to them. As a rule, I never do that to avoid any surprise Faceless attacks (or activating extra pods).

Comment: @ChrisHayes That's kind of the point. Take the risk, earn the reward. Or don't, and don't.

Comment: @ChrisHayes a Scout Ranger with the Phantom and Conceal abilities are really good to use on retaliation missions, you can quickly (and relatively safely) save a bunch of civilians while the rest of your squad fights aliens. If you give them a Battle Scanner, they can even spot Faceless without being revealed.

Comment: So I just saved 6 civilians in my last retaliation mission, and I didn't actually get an additional contact. Maybe it's because I've actually contacted all regions already?

Comment: I just rescued 9/13, and I received nothing special.  Region got +36 supplies/month.  No new scientist, engineer, or soldier.  I did get 1 resistance contact, and... maybe some supplies?