# Is there a downside to killing civilians outside of retaliation missions?

Tags: xcom-2

I encountered the dark event where Faceless appear on missions besides retaliation missions. I've found the most effective way to find faceless is to throw grenades at civilians. If they die, they were a civilian; if they survive, they're a faceless.

Is there a downside to killing civilians in this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell if a civilian is a Faceless?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254720/how-can-i-tell-if-a-civilian-is-a-faceless)

Comment: @DavidYell These are two different questions, although the practical answer to this is probably contained in that other question, being that targeting civilians with grenades brings up a warning while targeting Faceless doesn't.

Comment: @DavidYell The Faceless thing was an example. I also kill civilians when they're in the way or are annoying me. The other question doesn't discuss that.

Comment: What a waste of perfectly good grenades!

Comment: If you look at it from the civilian's POV, I would said that probably yes... :-D

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It's not. It's about the civilians who *aren't* in retaliation missions and cannot be saved.

Comment: Whoops, you're right.  Comment removed and +1 for the question :)

Comment: Righto, I've retracted my close vote, but I would recommend an edit to the question to make it more specific and thus easier to differentiate.

Comment: While the question phrasing makes it slightly different from http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254597/is-there-a-point-in-saving-more-civilians-in-xcom-2 I think the overall answer is the same...

Comment: @taegost See my previous comment and the new question title. This is not about retaliation missions.

Comment: @Studoku - Ah I see your clarification now.  I haven't come across any missions outside of the Retaliation ones that had civilians that mattered...  Or is that what you're talking about?  The civvies just standing around that flee when the combat starts but don't actually have a counter tied to them?

Comment: How about the guilt of killing innocent unarmed civillians?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no downside to killing civilians.  I've killed hundreds of civs in hijack, defense, and guerilla op missions with no impact on either the mission rating, the well being of my troops, or the well being of my own mind.

That's right, you can still get Flawless ratings from missions even if you kill civilians.

The way I see it, if they don't get out of your way, they become cannon fodder.

Comment: In my opinion this answer would have been even better without the last sentence. We should stick to facts around the stack exchange.